# Showing that $\epsilon F$ is a natural transformation

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, functors

I'm trying to prove that that the naturality squares commute for the natural transformation $\epsilon F$ defined by $(\epsilon F)_A=\epsilon_{F(A)}:FGF(A)\to F(A)$ where $\epsilon$ is the counit of adjunction between $F$ and $G$ ($F$ on the left and $G$ on the right). So I need to prove that for any arrow $f:A\to A'$ in the domain category of $F$, the following square commutes

[image]

The only idea I had is to use the commutativity of the naturality squares for $\epsilon_X$:

[image]

But I don't see how to do it. Applying $F$ to this diagram wouldn't make any sense.  I could consider a diagram with vertical arrows $GF(X)\to X$ with $X=A,A'$ and apply $F$ but that diagram doesn't make sense to me, why would it be commutative (the naturality squares for the unit of adjunction $\eta$ should go in the opposite direction)?

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Your first naturality square is just your second square applied at the morphism $\alpha = F(f): F(A) \rightarrow F(A')$.

That is, the naturality square for $\epsilon$ commutes for every morphism $\alpha$ in the source category of $G$. $F(f)$ is one specific morphism in the source category of $G$, so we can substitute it in as a possible $\alpha$ and get a commuting square.

This works for all $f:A \rightarrow A'$, so we get all the commuting squares we need for a natural transformation $FGF \Rightarrow F$.

Comment: I thought about this, but if we use this proof, don't we get that my first naturality square commutes for all arrows of the form $F(f):F(A)\to F(A')$, and not for all arrows $f:A\to A'$? Or does the former imply the latter? If so, why?

Comment: Arrows $f:A \rightarrow A'$ and arrows $Ff: FA \rightarrow FA'$ are different sorts of things; they live in different categories. Every arrow $f: A \rightarrow A'$ gives rise to an arrow $Ff: FA \rightarrow FA'$ when you apply the functor $F$ to it, so we can use the naturality square at $Ff$ when checking the naturality square at $f$ (Since they are the same square).

Comment: What "All arrows of the form $Ff$, but not all arrows," shows us is that we can't go backwards. It's possible for $\epsilon_F$ to be a natural transformation but for $\epsilon$ not to be natural, because the naturality squares could work for all arrows of the form $Ff:FA \rightarrow FA'$ to work but not for all arrows $\alpha:X \rightarrow X'$. (I've never seen this come up, though.)